# Filter e-mails in outlook addressed to X people

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I would like to be able to filter e-mails which are sent to more then, for instance, 15 people? Is something like this achievable? In Outlook 2016? 
Or is something like this possible to create using macro's / visual basic with the developer options?

The question is not a duplicate since I ask for a filter, not a warning when I accidently sent an e-mail to +15 people.

Comment: I ask for a filter not a warning.

Comment: A macro can do more than just issue a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim item As MailItem
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objFolderInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objFolderDL As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set objNS = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolderInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objFolderDL = objFolderInbox.Folders("E-mail DL")

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Split collection
    arr = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")

    ' For each new e-mail / event / etc
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        ' Set item
        Set item = objNS.GetItemFromID(arr(i))

        ' Check if e-mail
        If item.Class = olMail Then
            Set olItem = item
            Set Recips = olItem.Recipients

            ' Check if number of recipients > 15
            If Recips.Count > 15 Then
                ' Move to different folder
                olItem.Move objFolderDL
            End If
        End If
    Next

ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```